# how to get the right version loader with webpack 4

Tags: webpack

webpack have updated to version 5,
but I have to use webpack 4 on my project.
Everytime when I try to install a loader or plugin, such as css-loader:

```sh
npm install css-loader -D
```

npm download the lastest version that does not support webpack 4.

It's very tedious if I try to read all the loaders's `CHANGELOG.md` one by one then figure out which version is worked for webpack 4.

Is any smart way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact issue recently and I just tried limiting the installation by major version with npm, because I believe changing the version of webpack is a breaking change.

First, I saw that the last major version released today was 6.X so I tried with version 5.

`npm install --save-dev css-loader@^5`

And it worked and that way I am sure that I will install the latest release for the version 5.

Hope this helps.